# Python - binascii.unhexlify and .decode("hex") return TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found

Tags: python

I've searched this extensively but cannot find a post that fixes this issue. I have a simple string that I've received from a modem of `82001B014042`. I want to disregard the preceding header of `82001B01` and decode the hex digits `4042`. My code is as follows;

```
rxHEX = ser.readline()
print rxHEX         #82001B014042
rxData = rxHEX[8:]  #4042
print rxData
#rxData = "4042"
rxData = rxData.decode("hex")
#rxData = binascii.unhexlify(rxData)
print rxData
```

Regardless if I use `.decode("hex")` or `binascii.unhexlify(rxData)` I receive

> *TypeError: Non-hexadecimal digit found*

If I un-hash `#rxData = "4042"` it returns *@S* which is what I'd expect.

Why won't it work from what is received from the modem string?

If I only have

```
rxHEX = ser.readline()
print rxHEX
rxData = rxHEX[8:]
print rxData
I recieve
```

The output is

> 82001F014042
>   4042

Comment: And if you print the `repr()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using `.readline()`, your string most likely contains a newline (or CRLF pair) at the end. Therefore, you should try `rxData = rxHEX[8:].strip()`.

Answer (score 0):

`readline` doesn't strip trailing newlines. Use `rsHEX.rstrip('\r\n')` to remove trailing newlines on any OS, or `rsHEX.strip()` to just drop all leading and trailing whitespace of any kind.